# How to get start/end date from single date column from an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

could you please help me to get a solution for my issue. I was using sybase database.

I have two table trans_status, trans_ref

trans_status :-

```
| Corre_ID | Pro_type |      Desc |                Datetime |
|----------|----------|-----------|-------------------------|
|   ABC_01 |    Books |   Started | 17/02/2016 00:17:18.963 |
|   ABC_01 |    Books | Inprocess | 17/02/2016 00:18:18.963 |
|   ABC_01 |    Books |  Finished | 17/02/2016 00:19:18.963 |
|   ABC_02 |     XXXX |   Started | 16/02/2016 00:17:18.963 |
|   ABC_02 |     XXXX | Inprocess | 16/02/2016 00:18:18.963 |
|   ABC_02 |     XXXX |  Finished | 16/02/2016 00:19:18.963 |
|   ABC_03 |     yyyy |   Started | 15/02/2016 00:17:18.963 |
|   ABC_03 |     yyyy | Inprocess | 15/02/2016 00:18:18.963 |
|   ABC_03 |     yyyy |  Finished | 15/02/2016 00:19:18.963 |
|   ABC_04 |     zzzz |   Started | 14/02/2016 00:19:18.963 |
```

trans_ref :-

```
| Payment_ID | Corre_ID |
|------------|----------|
|       1111 |   ABC_01 |
|       2222 |   ABC_02 |
|       3333 |   ABC_03 |
|       4444 |   ABC_04 |
```

Desired Output :-

```
Corre_ID-----Payment_ID-----StartDate-----EndDate-----Response Time in Hours
ABC_01-----1111-----17/02/2016 00:17:18.963-----17/02/2016 00:19:18.963-----1
ABC_02-----2222-----16/02/2016 00:17:18.963-----16/02/2016 00:19:18.963-----1
ABC_03-----3333-----15/02/2016 00:17:18.963-----15/02/2016 00:19:18.963-----1
ABC_04-----4444-----14/02/2016 00:19:18.963-----EMPTY-----EMPTY
```

could you please help me to build an sql query please. Here my description was not standard all the time.

Comment: You have to explain the logic of how achive that desire result, we can try to guess, but is a waste of our time. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: HI Juan,  Thanks for responding to my question. I have already tried a lot . but still not getting designed output. If you can help me with you technical expertise, It will be a great help.

Comment: As I say, I cant help until you explain what logic you need apply to get that result, and read the link I provide so you learn how make better questions

Comment: based on the both tables i want correction id from trans_status table and corresponding paymentId from trans_ref table. And also for the correlation id when the transaction was started i.e min(date) and if there is one more record present for that correlation id then i need max(date). But in the result i need unique correlation id and then payment id and also start date as min(datetime) and end_date as max(datetime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want is this:

```
SELECT t.Corre_ID,s.Payment_ID,
       max(case when t.Desc = 'Started' then t.Datetime end) as startDate,
       max(case when t.Desc = 'Finished' then t.Datetime end) as startDate,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,max(case when t.Desc = 'Started' then t.Datetime end),
                     max(case when t.Desc = 'Inprocess' then t.Datetime end)) as response
FROM trans_status t 
INNER JOIN trans_ref s ON (t.Corre_ID = s.Corre_ID)
GROUP BY t.Corre_ID,s.Payment_ID
```

If I understood correctly, then the response time is the difference between start_date and inprocess date

Answer (score 0):

You must join the trans_status Table twice to get the start and end date. Since the end date may be missing you have to make the second join a left join. Try the following query:

```
SELECT
  r.Corre_ID,
  Payment_ID,
  s_start.Datetime AS StartDate,
  s_end.Datetime AS EndDate,
  TIMEDIFF(s_end.Datetime, s_start.Datetime) AS 'Response Time in Hours'
FROM
  trans_ref r JOIN trans_status s_start ON (r.Corre_ID = s_start.Corre_ID AND s_start.Desc = 'Started')
              LEFT JOIN trans_status s_end ON (r.Corre_ID = s_end.Corre_ID AND s_end.Desc = 'Finished')
```

If the process is not finished, the fields EndDate and 'Response Time in Hours' will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sd.Corre_ID, sd.Payment_ID, sd.Datetime StartDate, ed.Datetime EndDate, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ed.EndDate, sd.StartDate) `Response Time in Hours` 
FROM
    (SELECT ts.Corre_ID, tr.Payment_ID, ts.Datetime
    FROM trans_status ts
    JOIN trans_ref tr on ts.Corre_ID = tr.Corre_ID
    WHERE ts.Desc = 'Started'
    GROUP BY ts.Corre_ID) sd
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ts.Corre_ID, tr.Payment_ID, ts.Datetime
    FROM trans_status ts
    JOIN trans_ref tr on ts.Corre_ID = tr.Corre_ID
    WHERE ts.Desc = 'Finished'
    GROUP BY ts.Corre_ID) ed
    on sd.Corre_ID = ed.Corre_ID
```

PS. This is MySQL syntax, not sure if it's same for Sybase.